# Waht is the difference between Shwalbe's Basic compound and Performance compound tyres?

Tags: tire, shopping

[Schwalbe](http://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/off-road_tires) produces a wide range of tyres. Their "Basic compound" [tyres](http://screambikes.eu/en/26-tyres/1945-schwalbe-land-cruiser-26-x-190-tire.html) are twice cheaper than the same model but with "Performance compound".

Anyone have user experience with the two product lines? What are the practical differences? Are the Performance line MTB tyres made of "soft" rubber, that provides superior grip?

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, well, at least one person, who has tried the same tyre in the two variants, would be a good guideline. Something along the lines of "no real difference" or "significantly better grip".

Comment: Haven't ridden both, so I won't leave a proper answer. I switched from a continental basic compound (~$40) to Schwab performance (~$65). The tires grip better, but somehow feel less sticky on the road during acceleration. Absolutely worth the money for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified way to think about this is a tire has three core attributes: performance, durability and cost, but you can optimize for only two of them.  That, and marketing, is what seems to be afoot.

Schwalbe's web site has some general information on the [construction](http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/tire_construction) of tires.  A takeway is they can tweak the rubber compounds to improve a tire's characteristics for specific needs. Their very high-level/marketing view [list enumerating compounds](http://www.schwalbetires.com/sites/all/definitions/Compound.html) equates the "Triple Star" compound as the best family, but it's tuned the specific user type mountain (grip, speed), road (speed, weight) and touring (durability, fewer flats) use.  It's not that different from 105/Dura Ace vs XT/XTR.

It may be more helpful to consider their [suitability ratings](http://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/off-road_tires/all_mountain) within each category.  For example, under the [All Mountain](http://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/off-road_tires/all_mountain), the Nobby Nic (with the PaceStar, the high-end compound) is touted for its grip in soft surfaces and decent on hardpack/loose.  Its other virtues are comparable to the Rapid Rob (standard compound) at approximately 60% of the cost.  Thus if grip on soft-pack is really important to you, you might be willing spend more.  Skimming through their touring tires, there does seem to be a tradeoff between speed/grip and protection/durability.

Schwalbe's breakout seems reasonable, though I'd like to see some comparables with other vendors for calibration, ideally by the folks at [Bicycle Quarterly](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/bicycle-quarterly-performance-of-tires/) who have done work trying to quantify aspects such as inflation pressure vs tire width.

Hope this helps.